owl carousel stop snap to next item
I have following settings for owl carousel
carousel.owlCarousel({
        nav: false,
        loop: false,
        dots: false,
        pagination: false,
        autoWidth: false,
        autoHeight: false,
        responsive:{
            0:{
                items:2,
                margin: 10,
            },
            600:{
                items: 3,
                margin: 20,
            },
            1200:{
                items:4,
                margin: 30,
            },
            1800:{
                items:5,
                margin: 40,
            }
        }
    });

I want a smooth scroll on touch move or mouse drag, but carousel auto snaps to next item, how can I stop it so that the carousel stops where the touch ends, instead of snap movement to next or previous item.
